# Command Prompt: dir file whose File size is greater than 1024KB

Tags: windows, list, command, prompt

I am currently using the following command to find out how many documents with pdf format is there with there complete path but it shows the list of like 11,000 documents,

```
dir *.pdf /s /b**
```

I'd like to list only those images that has the file size greater than 1024KB , the file size shouldn't be displayed yet the file should be greater than 1024KB in size.

is that possible using command prompt ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using windows, you will most likely have [powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714415(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
ls *.pdf | where-object {$_.length -gt 1048576} | format-table -property Name
```

`ls` will list the files with `.pdf` extensions.  `where-object` will filter the result set to files with length greater than 1MB (1048576 = 1MB).  `format-table` will format the final output to display only the name of the file